# Injecting EJB within JAX-RS resource in JBoss 5

Tags: rest, jboss, ejb, jax-rs, jboss5.x

Although there already are quite some StackOverflow questions, blog entries, etc. on the web, I still cannot figure out a solution to the problem stated below.

Similar to this question ([Injecting EJB within JAX-RS resource on JBoss7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166708/injecting-ejb-within-jax-rs-resource-on-jboss7)) I'd like to inject a EJB instance into a JAX-RS class. I tried with JBoss 5, JBoss 7, and WildFly 8. I either get no injection at all (field is null), or the server does not deploy (as soon as I try to combine all sorts of annotations).
Adding `@Stateless` to the JAX-RS makes the application server know both classes as beans. However, no injection takes place.

Is there a way to inject EJBs into a REST application? What kind of information (in addition to that contained in the question linked to above) could I provide to help?

EDIT: I created a Github project showing code that works (with Glassfish 4.0) and does not work (with JBoss 5).

https://github.com/C-Otto/beantest

- Commit 4bf2f3d23f49d106a435f068ed9b30701bbedc9d works using Glassfish
  4.0.
- Commit 50d137674e55e1ceb512fe0029b9555ff7c2ec21 uses Jersey 1.8, which does not work.
- Commit 86004b7fb6263d66bda7dd302f2d2a714ff3b939
  uses Jersey 2.6, which also does not work.

EDIT2:
Running the Code which I tried on JBoss 5 on Glassfish 4.0 gives:

```
Exception while loading the app : CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [Ref<ContainerRequest>] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.UriRoutingContext(Ref<ContainerRequest>, ProcessingProviders)]
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [Ref<ContainerRequest>] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.UriRoutingContext(Ref<ContainerRequest>, ProcessingProviders)]
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:403)
```

EDIT3: The crucial information might be that I'd like a solution that works on JBoss 5

Comment: please post the relevant code.

Comment: I thought this guy explained it pretty well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027834/inject-a-ejb-into-jax-rs-restfull-service

Comment: actually there is a way and basically you don't have to do anything special to achieve it. Your JAX-RS resource should be an EJB itself and that is enough. Problem must be somewhere in your code. So I would agree with Camilo here. Seeing your code might help to understand the problem

Comment: I added the code, please have another look. Thanks!

Comment: Jesus Mireles, I tried that before, sadly it does not help.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to make your JAX-RS resource an EJB too (`@Stateless`) and then use `@EJB` or `@Resource` to inject it, you can always go with JNDI lookup (I tend to write a "ServiceLocator" class that gets a service via its class.

A nice resource to read about the topic:

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Remote+EJB+invocations+via+JNDI+-+EJB+client+API+or+remote-naming+project

A sample code:

```
try {
     // 1. Retreive the Home Interface using a JNDI Lookup
     // Retrieve the initial context for JNDI.       // No properties needed when local
      Context context = new InitialContext();

      // Retrieve the home interface using a JNDI lookup using
      // the java:comp/env bean environment variable        // specified in web.xml
      helloHome = (HelloLocalHome) context.lookup("java:comp/env/ejb/HelloBean");

     //2. Narrow the returned object to be an HelloHome object.      // Since the client is local, cast it to the correct object type.
     //3. Create the local Hello bean instance, return the reference 
      hello = (HelloLocal)helloHome.create();

    } catch(NamingException e) {

    } catch(CreateException e) {

    }
```

This is not "injecting" per-se, but you don't use "new" as-well, and you let the application server give you an instance which is managed.

I hope this was useful and I'm not telling you something you already know!

**EDIT:**

This is an excellent example: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI

**EDIT 2:**
As you stated in your comment, you'd like to inject it via annotations.
If the JNDI lookup is currently working for you without problems, and
If you're using Java EE 6+ (which I'm guessing you are), you can do the following:

```
@EJB(lookup = "jndi-lookup-string-here")
private RemoteInterface bean;
```

Comment: Sadly, this is our current work around approach. I _do_ want to use annotations and adding @Stateless or anything similar did not help.